# What editing guideline did I violate by adding a fitting tag?

Tags: discussion, editing, tagging

I added the "backuppc" tag to an old question about a specific BackupPC setting here: https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/5138

This got rejected by user [Chris S](https://serverfault.com/users/33417/chris-s). What guideline did I violate with this edit? I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Question is over a year and a half old and I didn't feel it needed to be dug up just to add a scarcely used tag. If you really feel it adds value to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) and the Question having that particular tag added, I'll be glad to toss it in there, I just don't see it myself.

Side note: There are no "penalties" or detraction for having a edit rejected. My history shows 422 approved and 81 rejected, so you're not the first by a long shot.

Comment: +1. I would have rejected this as "edit is to minor" to avoid pushing this old stuff back to the front page for a mostly irrelevant edit.

Comment: @SvenW Probably should have done that, but Manchester just tied up the game so I wasn't quite concentrating on SF. =]

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I wouldn't mind even if there was a penalty for rejected edits, I just like to know that sort of stuff when working on community-driven sites :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would have allowed it. I realize that it's old, but the question is specifically about BackupPC. The question itself is a valid one (it hasn't been closed or downvoted) and tags exist as a way of indexing and organizing questions.